# Convert lat long string into google maps API LatLng Object

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps-api-3, latitude-longitude

I am trying to convert a lat long string (53.3603, -6.315050000000042) into a google maps object in this  format: B: -6.26747649999993 k: 53.339251

I have used this function which works for the long but returns Nan for the lat.

```
function getLatLngFromString(ll) {
        var lat = ll.replace(/\s*\,.*/, ''); // first 123
        var lng = ll.replace(/.*,\s*/, ''); // second ,456
        var locate = new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(lat), parseFloat(lng)); 
        return locate;
    }
    ;
```

I am storing the lat long in a html tag as it called to a list view connected to a map. It is stored here in the correct format however when I retrieve it using the jQuery .attr it converts it to a string.

```
var location = $(this).closest('.allList').attr("position");
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 17):

Assuming the lat/lng string looks like "10.5, -0.51"

```
function getLatLngFromString(ll) {
    var latlng = ll.split(/, ?/)
    return new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(latlng[0]), parseFloat(latlng[1])); 
}
```

Should work

Comment: Thanks. However it's still returning k: NaN, B: -6.315050000000042, .

Comment: There was brackets around the edge which were getting caught. Used this: function getLatLngFromString(location) {
            var latlang = location.replace(/[()]/g,'');
            var latlng = latlang.split(',');
            //console.log(latlang);
            locate = new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(latlng[0]) , parseFloat(latlng[1]));
            return locate;
        }

Comment: You saved my day! Thanks.