# Convert String to LatLng

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

I'm using Google Maps API v2 and I get a location coordinates single String "-34.8799074,174.7565664" from my SharedPreferences that I need to convert to LatLng.

Can anyone help with this please?

Thx!

Comment: Ans: refer https://stackoverflow.com/a/26891191/4425004

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert lat long string into google maps API LatLng Object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26890514/convert-lat-long-string-into-google-maps-api-latlng-object)

Answer (score 54, accepted):

**[Google Maps Android API]**

You can split the string by comma and then parse the string to long

```
String[] latlong =  "-34.8799074,174.7565664".split(",");
double latitude = Double.parseDouble(latlong[0]);
double longitude = Double.parseDouble(latlong[1]);
```

To constructs a [LatLng](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/LatLng) with the given latitude and longitude coordinates

```
LatLng location = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
```

**[Google Maps JavaScript API]**

To do same operation with Maps JavaScript API service ([JSFiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/tn7rtdjp/17/)) -

```
  var latlong =  '-34.397,150.644'.split(',');
  var latitude = parseFloat(latlong[0]);
  var longitude = parseFloat(latlong[1]);
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 8,
    center: {lat: latitude, lng: longitude}
  };
```

Comment: unlike the other answer, this doesn't explain that LatLng is a class

Comment: @Muz I had updated the answer with more details and examples of usages.

Answer (score 16):

Firstly you will want to split the string on the comma:

```
String[] latLng = "-34.8799074,174.7565664".split(",");
```

This will then give you two `String` variables, which you will want to parse as doubles like so because the `LatLng` constructor takes two doubles for the latitude and longitude of the location:

```
double latitude = Double.parseDouble(latLng[0]);
double longitude = Double.parseDouble(latLng[1]);
```

Finally, adding to the previous answer, you will then want to put these into a `LatLng` object which is the class frequently used by Google Maps:

```
LatLng location = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
String convert = "-34.8799074,174.7565664";
Location location = new Location(convert);
LatLng location2 = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(),location.getLongitude());
```

Comment: new Location(String) api takes a provider like gps, or network.  This will not convert your string the way you are thinking.