# How to get Latitude from string value?

Tags: android, location

The Location value is getting from our server, in string format now I define new location after that i want to get the longitude and latitude but it's 0.0.
Code is like this.

```
String location = "lat\/lng: (28.6988812,77.1153696)";
Location loc = new Location(location);
double lat = loc.getLatitude();
double longitude = loc.getLongitude();
```

Comment: have a look [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27261715/5110595)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per Android documentation you need to pass location provider in the constructor.
Refer https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html#Location(java.lang.String)

You need to parse the string ("lat/lng: (28.6988812,77.1153696)") that you are getting from you server, extract latitude and longitude and pass those values to your location object using setLatitude() and setLongitude() function.

Answer (score 0):

You can extract latitude and longitude from the location string you got from the server with regex. Like this:

```
Double latitude = 0., longitude = 0.;

    //your location
    String location = "lat/long: (28.6988812,77.1153696)";
    //pattern
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("lat/long: \\(([0-9.]+),([0-9.]+)\\)$");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(location);
    if (matcher.matches()) {
        latitude = Double.valueOf(matcher.group(1));
        longitude = Double.valueOf(matcher.group(2));
    }
```

if you need a Location object:

```
Location targetLocation = new Location("");//provider name is unnecessary
targetLocation.setLatitude(latitude);//your coords of course
targetLocation.setLongitude(longitude);
```

thanks to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17983974/8471329)